# Javascript on AJAX with jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

-

how can I handle it, to get Javascript is working after the Ajax call?

On my page (wordpress) - I have all posts on startpage. I have built in a filtersystem with which the user can filter the posts after specific stuff - like "newest, most viewed, highlighted"

I use this function beneath to make this filter work:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
    $("#new").click(function(){

        var post_id = $(this).attr("rel")
        $(".postbox_wrapper").html('<span class="filter_posts">
<img src="<?php bloginfo ('template_directory'); ?>/images/287.gif"></span>');
        $(".postbox_wrapper").load(jQuery(this).attr("href") + " .postbox_wrapper")
        return false;
    });
});
```

The visitior clicks on the button "new" and the posts are filtered - only the newest posts show up. But I use Javascript to have the post count of disqus, lazy image loader, etc. these JS Files are not loaded on the filtered posts. (taxonomy.php)

this here is e.g. an JS File, which would be neccessary to make lazy loader available to the filtered posts:

```
http://myurl/../plugins/bj-lazy-load/js/bjll.min.js?ver=0.4.0
```

The question is: How can I tell in the function above, to also use the JS script on the new loaded "filtered" page.

It's a bit like this: [Use Ajax() function in Jquery to load PART of an external page into div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628065/use-ajax-function-in-jquery-to-load-part-of-an-external-page-into-div)

but I didn't get it to work....

thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you rephrase your question(be more precise)? I don't get what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question.
Are you trying to load a script after loading a particular content in a div?

If it is try this:

```
$(function(){
    $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});

    $("#new").click(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        var $PostboxWrapper = $(".postbox_wrapper");

        var post_id = $this.attr("rel")

        //I think you want load something like a loading .gif in taht point. Right?
        $PostboxWrapper.html(
            "<span class='filter_posts'>" + 
            "   <img src='<?php bloginfo ('template_directory'); ?>/images/287.gif'>" +
            "</span>"
        );

        $(".postbox_wrapper").load(jQuery(this).attr("href"), function()
        {
            $.getScript(
                "http://yourUrl/../plugins/bj-lazy-load/js/bjll.min.js?ver=0.4.0",
                function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
                    console.log('Load was performed.');
                }
            );
        })
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: hi Jorge - thanks for the reply! Yes - exactly. I try to load the js into the ajax loaded page. I am trying your code - but it's loading the complete page into the div

Comment: the js should just be passed to the new loaded page...I guess this getScript stuff is the right way. But it doesn's work