# How to iframe a specific part of a website?

Tags: html, css, iframe

```
<div style="border: 3px solid rgb(201, 0, 1); overflow: hidden; max-width: 736px;">
<iframe scrolling="no" src="http://freegeoip.net/" style="border: 0px none; margin-left: -20px; height: 448px; margin-top: -98px; width: 100%;">
</iframe>
</div>
```

My current code, I want to iframe the map of freegeoip.net and show on my website for the visitor, but I get this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNazG.png

As you can see there is empty space on the right side and I don't know how to fix that one... tried everything.

Comment: What do you mean by smaller iframe?

Comment: Make iframe smaller so it would fit the map size

Comment: How? I tried changing the values and this is the best I could come up with... when I try to change something from now on, everything goes weird..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know it's not really what you asked but you could just use their API its not that hard to program it into a Google Map using the Google map API. I made a small(fast) example for you.

```
$.getJSON('http://freegeoip.net/json/', function(data) {
    lat = data.latitude;
    lng = data.longitude;

    initialize();
});
```

**Working example:**
http://jsfiddle.net/qx4KF/

it will search your IP and display it on the map, you can also add some markers on the map to create the same view as freegeoip.net. For the marker you can use something like:

```
 var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng,
                map: map,
                title: 'Hello World!'
 });
```

**More about the Google map API: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/**

Answer (score 0):

If `javascript` and the `jQuery` library is not a problem you could use the `load` method in `jQuery` to **load part of an external page** using the dom element id of the div you want to get for example.

See [Use Ajax() function in Jquery to load PART of an external page into div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628065/use-ajax-function-in-jquery-to-load-part-of-an-external-page-into-div)

**Update**

The .load() method allows to specify a portion of the remote document to be inserted

```
$( "#result" ).load("http://freegeoip.net/ #map");
```

See http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Unfortunately, it's a problem in this case, as the website I'm getting iframew from doesn't offer this.. nor it's my own website.

Comment: what is exactly the part of the freegeoip index page you want to display? only the map?

Comment: The map. I want to make it for the visitor to show his place on the map.

Comment: The map is located in an iframe with id "map".