# Loading a page then loading just the div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using some JQuery to load a div from another page to the current page, the problem I am having is that the content is the div does not exist until that page has loaded.

```
<div id="placeholder"></div>
```

What I am trying to do is load the page first (So the content goes into the div) and then I want to load the div in the current page.

Currently I have something which looks like this:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<div class="panel-body">
    <div id="bar-chart-db" class="height-sm"></div>
</div>

<script>
    $( "#bar-chart-db" ).load( "../index.aspx #placeholder" );
</script>
```

Is what I want to do possible and if it is, any suggestions?

Comment: Is that space in the URL deliberate?

Comment: Possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628065/use-ajax-function-in-jquery-to-load-part-of-an-external-page-into-div

Answer (score 0):

you have to wrap the jquery in a document ready function:

```
$(function(){
    $( "#bar-chart-db" ).load( "../index.aspx #placeholder" );
});
```

Here is something you might want to read: [Document Ready Function](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Comment: Still no luck even when I did this

Comment: @Jessica Is the space in the URL meant to be there?

Comment: Yeah, I can get the content from the div no problem, it's just causing me a problem when I want to load the data before hand.

Comment: Nope, none, I just checked again to make sure and nope, 0

Comment: well my guess would be that "../index.aspx #placeholder" is not returning anything.  Is there valid html in the placeholder element?

Comment: No, I've said already I can get the content from the div, it's just that it's not loading the the content that will be displayed in the div if the paged loaded normally, I need to load the page and then get the content from the div

Comment: what populates the div if the page "loads normally"?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203762/when-loading-an-html-page-via-ajax-will-script-tags-be-loaded